# refresh JFrame after adding new Components

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

I want to add some new Components to my JFrame during runtime when a button is pressed.
This works so far, but i have to resize the window manually to see the new components.

Is there any Action I can fire or a method to call to refresh the window? Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have to `revalidate();` the frame. If that doesn't work you also have to call `repaint();`

Comment: ok had to hack a little bit arround in my classes but it works! (btw you did mean validate() right? ;))

Comment: indeed, since JFrame is already a top level container, you just can call validate();.

Comment: Well, generally components are added to a JPanel, not the frame directly, so you would revalidate the panel.

Comment: repaint works and revalidate does not - any idea why?

Answer (score 9):

Call

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

`revalidate` tells the layout manager to reset based on the new component list. This will also trigger a call to repaint.

`repaint` is used to tell a component to repaint itself.

Answer (score 0):

in java `repaint();` working for me. while `revalidate();` not working for me.