# How to refresh a JFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

So in my program I set in the beginning a JLabel to it so now an image is on it.  Now I need to remove that JLabel and put a new one instead of it. So I did:

```
frame.remove(test_loadingJL);
frame.add(test_lockScreenJL);
```

But when I look, it is still the first image and it doesn't update until I resize the actual window manually.  Is there a way to update the frame so I don't have to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work `frame.revalidate()`

Answer (score 0):

Your Choices:

```
 1.SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(name of Component(in your example is frame)

SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);

2.frame.dispose();

frame.setVisible(true);

3.revalidate();

  revalidate();//<------------needed when add/remove components
  repaint();//sometimes needed also, sometimes not
```

Also check this link [possible dublicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718435/refresh-jframe-after-adding-new-components)
same question [here](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/72326-java-update-swing-components/)

These should work

Answer (score 0):

Try calling frame.setVisible(true) before adding the components.